# How to make only selected Columns editable in ShieldUI Grid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, shieldui

I am using ShieldUI for making an editable Grid on a webpage. A very similar grid can be found at [this URL](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/bootstrap-editable-jquery-grid).

My requirement is **to make only 1 column editable while keeping the remaining columns as non-editable** in the above Grid.

The [Documentation of the ShieldUI](http://www.shieldui.com/documentation/grid) provides option to enable or disable editing of the whole Grid at a time. However, it provides no option to enable or disable editing at column level.

I could not find any good resource on the web on this topic.

As a possible solution, we can enforce the edit disable using Javascript, but I think that would destroy its simplicity.

How can we achieve this? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I was having a similar problem, I used the editorCreating event to enable/disable the default control behavior. I am using row editing in this example.

https://www.shieldui.com/documentation/grid/javascript/api/events/editor-creating

Ex.

```
events: {
     editorCreating: function(e) {
        if (e.field == "column_i_want_to_disable") {
            e.options = { enabled: false };
         }
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to cancel the editing on a row by overriding the command event, described here:
https://www.shieldui.com/documentation/grid/javascript/api/events/command

Before a row goes in editing mode, an "edit" command is sent, which can be caught by the command event described above.

Inside the event handler you can inspect the *row* being edited and cancel the editing it if needed.